# How to ensure `make` rebuilds all objects after deletion of a file

Tags: makefile

Consider the following `Makefile` skeleton:

```
HEADERS := $(shell find . -name "*.h" | sort)
SOURCES := $(shell find . -name "*.c" | sort)
OBJECTS := $(patsubst %.c, %.o, $(SOURCES))

executable: $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $(OBJECTS)

%.o: %.c
    rm -f $@
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $< || { rm -f $@; exit 1; }

$(OBJECTS): Makefile $(HEADERS)
```

These rules ensure that `OBJECTS` and `executable` are recompiled if any of the following files is modified:

- Declaration files (*.h)
- Implementation files (*.c)
- The `Makefile` itself

This works very nicely. It also covers the case of adding a new source code file to a directory of the project (assuming the new file wasn't added using `cp -a` or `mv`). The case that isn't covered is the deletion of a file.

Recompilation on deletion is useful because it catches leftovers in the remaining source code and because it removes superfluous data from the `executable`.

*What is a succinct and efficient way of ensuring the `make` command rebuilds all objects after a source code file is deleted from the project?*

The answer can use any common Linux command via `$(shell ...)`.

Comment: This makefile rebuilds every file whenever any file changes.  I don't really see the point in using `make` at all here; you can just write a shell script that recompiles every file every time you run it, and call that script instead of `make` and get almost the same behavior.  The only difference is that if _no_ files have changed then nothing is done.

Comment: Sorry, I misread: it only rebuilds all object files if any header file changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reply provided by MadScientist is very good (particularly regarting the use of a modern auto-generated dependencies method).

If the modern auto-generated dependencies method is not an option, an alternative to using `echo` and `cmp` would be to have the dependencies handled by `make`, using `include` and `$(file ...)` (note the extra dependency for `$(OBJECTS)`):

```
HEADERS := $(shell find . -name "*.h" | sort)
SOURCES := $(shell find . -name "*.c" | sort)
OBJECTS := $(patsubst %.c, %.o, $(SOURCES))

executable: $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $(OBJECTS)

%.o: %.c
    rm -f $@
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $< || { rm -f $@; exit 1; }

$(OBJECTS): Makefile $(HEADERS) deps.mk

include deps.mk

deps.mk: $(HEADERS) $(SOURCES)
    $(file >$@,$@: $(HEADERS) $(SOURCES))
    $(file >>$@,$(HEADERS) $(SOURCES):)
```

That is only one example and any combination of behavior is possible. For instance if your requirements were:

- recompile everything when

  - a header file is created or modified; or
  - a header or source file is deleted
- otherwise, recompile only the added or modified source files - if any

you could capture the list of deleted files in a `MISSING` using the `filter-out` function:

```
HEADERS := $(shell find . -name "*.h" | sort)
SOURCES := $(shell find . -name "*.c" | sort)
OBJECTS := $(patsubst %.c, %.o, $(SOURCES))

executable: $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $(OBJECTS)

%.o: %.c
    rm -f $@
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $< || { rm -f $@; exit 1; }

include missing.mk
ifneq (,$(MISSING))
$(MISSING):
endif

$(OBJECTS): Makefile $(HEADERS) $(MISSING)

missing.mk: $(MISSING) $(HEADERS) $(SOURCES)
    $(file >$@,MISSING=$$(filter-out $$(HEADERS) $$(SOURCES),$(HEADERS) $(SOURCES)))
```

Comment: deps.mk will not be updated if source or header file is deleted.

Comment: @AlexeySemenyuk It will. That's what the line `$(file >>$@,$(HEADERS) $(SOURCES):)` is for

Comment: Then the `$(file >$@,$@: $(HEADERS) $(SOURCES))` is not needed as it just duplicates `deps.mk: $(HEADERS) $(SOURCES)`

Comment: It is not the same `$(HEADERS) $(SOURCES)`. Before and after. Let's say you have `a.c`, `a1.h` and `a2.h`; the `$(file >$@,$@: $(HEADERS) $(SOURCES))` will write `deps.mk: a.c a1.h a2.h` into `deps.mk`. Then you remove `a2.h` and run `make`; `deps.mk` gets included, which injects the dependency to a2.h even though at that time `HEADERS` only contains `a1.h`.

Comment: It is needed, because you want to declare the dependencies from the LAST run of make into the deps.mk file, where those files existed, not the current run of make where HEADERS and SOURCES don't contain the deleted file.  Without that line deps.mk won't be rebuilt when you delete some files.

Comment: Oh, true. So complicated :)

Comment: Nice solution. However, the efficiency requirement of the question isn't allowing me to accept it as the right answer. Running `make --trace` revealed that executing the shell sequence `> a.c`, `make`, `> b.c`, `make`, `> c.c`, `make` will redundantly cause recompilation of all `*.c` files rather than compilation of just the added file.

Comment: @atomsymbol please edit your question to clarify your requirements (particularly the `efficiency requirement`). As you are explicitly requiring  *all* objects to be recompiled when a source file is deleted, please be very specific for the expected behavior under various combinations of additions, modifications and deletions of headers and source files. The detail of the solution really depends on the detail of the question.

Comment: I have decided to accept this answer. The other answers to the question are quite cool as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a listfile (name `listfile`) which contains the list of headers and `C` sources. If you delete a file from source tree you'll need to re-create this `listfile`. The `listfile` should be dependency in `Makefile`.

```
HEADERS := $(shell find . -name "*.h" | sort)
SOURCES := $(shell find . -name "*.c" | sort)
OBJECTS := $(patsubst %.c, %.o, $(SOURCES))

executable: $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $(OBJECTS)

%.o: %.c
    rm -f $@
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $< || { rm -f $@; exit 1; }

genlist:
    find . -name \*.c -or -name \*.h > listfile

$(OBJECTS): Makefile $(HEADERS) listfile

.PHONY: genlist
```

After deletion you should run `make genlist`.

Of course you can expand this idea: you'll create a listfile and every `make` will generate a temporary listfile (for example use `mktemp`) and compares to the "official" `listfile`. If they differ will overwrite the "official" `listfile` - and don't have to run `make genlist` after deletion.

Comment: Your phony syntax is wrong: it should be `.PHONY: genlist` (note colon).  Also, this is even more like a shell script than the original, because it will rebuild every file every time you invoke `make`, even if nothing has changed.

Comment: `.PHONY` syntax corrected, thanks. Everytime-rebuilding: yes, I saw that the `executable` target isn't too good but I think the original `Makefile` has a valid filename target (with proper `gcc`'s `-o`) because @atomsymbol wrote this is only a "`Makefile` skeleton". If no @atomsymbol should correct his `Makefile` :)

Comment: The problem isn't with the `executable` rule.  The problem is with the line `$(OBJECTS): Makefile $(HEADERS) listfile`.  Here you've made a phony target (that will be rebuilt every time you run `make`) a prerequisite of every object file.  That means all the object files will be considered out of date every time you run make, and everything will be rebuilt.

Comment: No, the `genlist` target will run when you run `make genlist`. Please note that the name of phony-target and the filename is different (and the `genlist` isn't dependency).

Comment: @MadScientist Making all `$(OBJECTS)` depend on `listfile` is correct because, as specified in the question, deletion of a file might render some of the *remaining* files uncompilable and I would like to catch such issues by simply running `make` from command-line.

Comment: Right, I missed that the target name and the generated filename were different.  However this requires that you remember to run `make genlist` before you run `make`, in order to get make to notice that some files were deleted.  If you want make to notice this without any special extra commands then you need to do something else.

Comment: Yes, it was the "expand the idea" :)

Answer (score 1):

One way to handle this would be to use a modern auto-generated dependencies method such as the one [described here](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/).  These methods have built-in properties that handle deleted files correctly.

If you don't want to do that, then something similar to what @uzsolt suggests is what you need to do, but you have to play a trick if you want to avoid the need to run `make genlist` explicitly before make realizes a file is missing:

```
HEADERS := $(shell find . -name "*.h" | sort)
SOURCES := $(shell find . -name "*.c" | sort)
OBJECTS := $(patsubst %.c, %.o, $(SOURCES))

executable: $(OBJECTS)
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $(OBJECTS)

%.o: %.c
        rm -f $@
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $< || { rm -f $@; exit 1; }

$(OBJECTS): Makefile $(HEADERS) sourcelist

sourcelist: FORCE
        @for f in $(SOURCES) $(HEADERS); do echo "$$f"; done > $@.tmp
        @[ `comm -23 $@ $@.tmp | wc -l` -eq 0 ] || mv $@.tmp $@

FORCE:
```

The idea here is that you compare the old list to the new list and only modify the list if the old list contains something that the new list doesn't.  This ensures that unless something is deleted the timestamp for `sourcelist` doesn't change, and so it won't force the object files to be out of date.

Comment: This is a nice solution. However the efficiency requirement in the question isn't allowing me to accept it as the right answer because of the redundant object recompilations after a *new* `file.c` is added to the project.

Comment: Good point.  I added a change that might work (not really tested).  However, I recommend you follow my first suggestion and use a real dependency generation method.

Comment: Isn't `printf` instead of `echo` needed to get newline characters in `$@.tmp`? `comm` is a line-based tool.

Comment: Oh, yes.  Well, I said not really tested :)

Answer (score 1):

Everybody suggests to generate auxiliary makefile. I quite support these suggestions. However I'd prefer to keep isolated generation of this makefile. Here is solution to keep it in a single $(shell ...) command:

```
THIS_MAKEFILE := $(lastword $(MAKEFILE_LIST))

$(if $(shell find -name '*.h' -or -name '*.c' | \
    awk '\
        /.*\.h$$/ { h=h " " $$0 } \
        /.*\.c$$/ { c=c " " $$0 } \
        END { \
          print "HEADERS :=" h; \
          print "SOURCES :=" c \
        }' > $(THIS_MAKEFILE).include.new && \
    diff -q $(THIS_MAKEFILE).include.new $(THIS_MAKEFILE).include 2> /dev/null || mv $(THIS_MAKEFILE).include.new $(THIS_MAKEFILE).include),)

include $(THIS_MAKEFILE).include
OBJECTS := $(patsubst %.c, %.o, $(SOURCES))

executable: $(OBJECTS); $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $(OBJECTS)

%.o: %.c; rm -f $@ && $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $< || { rm -f $@; exit 1; }

$(OBJECTS): $(THIS_MAKEFILE) $(THIS_MAKEFILE).include $(HEADERS)
```

`$(shell)` is wrapped in `$(if)` to suppress any output from it.
This solution has one $(shell) call instead of two and doesn't depend on relatively new $(file) GNU Make function.

Good for small project, but doesn't scale well.